# How to align image to top left of div

Tags: css

Below code :

**CSS**

```
#block { 
    border-width: 2px; 
    border-color: #4682B4; 
    background-color: #E0FFFF; 
    width: 200px; 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="block">
<h3>Test header</h3>

<p>
<img height="100" style="max-width: 120px;background-position: top left;" src="http://socialmediababe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/administrator.jpg" />
</p>

<p>
Test text
</p>
</div>
```

produces this :

[image]

How can I align image to top left corner of screen ?

By top left corner I mean align to point indicated by arrow :

[image]

I have tried 'background-position: top left;' but this does not make any difference.

After trying 'Fags' answer I receive same result :

[image]

Comment: background-position only works with images that are set using the background-image property, not the img tag.

Comment: can u put an image what is the desired output you are looking for?

Comment: use *{margin:0; padding:0} you get your solution :)

Comment: @user470184 what you want, exactly ask your question?

Comment: @user470184 CHECK DEMO1 I WILL UPDATE MY ANSWER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIke this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H4F8H/)**

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#block { 
    border-width: 2px; 
    border-color: #4682B4; 
    background-color: #E0FFFF; 
    width: 200px; 
    text-align: center; 
    line-height:30px;
    padding:3px 0;
}
```

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/H4F8H/11/)**

Comment: on Chrome it is still display image in same position ?

Comment: @user470184 please try in my chrome completely working, please refresh your page and then try it

Comment: @Fags I don't know whats going on, ive tried Chrome and FF but same result - its displaying image as before

Comment: @user470184  you write *{margin:0;padding:0;} in your attach stylesheet?

Comment: @Fags yes, ive just added a screenshot to original question

Comment: Just FYI, from the screenshot that you have attached, the result shows that you are achieving what you want. As I can see it stick to the top left in your screenshot. If this is what you do not want to achive, can you provide a screenshot of how you want? - @user470184

Comment: @user470184 CHECK **DEMO1** I WILL UPDATE MY ANSWER

Comment: FYI @Fags - The red arrow image that the user has provided conveys the image to stay on top.

Comment: @Fags that works, what does the * in *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

As per current code, try this fix; it is close to your desired result.

It might look a bit odd as background color for div is different than image.

PS: You can always have transparent image.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Akki619/KWYXA/)

```
#block { 
    border-width: 2px; 
    border-color: #4682B4; 
    background-color: #E0FFFF; 
    width: 200px; 
    text-align: center; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
   float:left;
}
```

If you have more img tags that need to be positioned please create css class or id for individual image styling.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements have a default behaviour, where they have a set value of margin, padding, line-height, etc. You need to first reset them and then customize them to your requriements.

You can check the below **[CSS RESET](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** link for your reference.

**The Code:**

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

You need to add the above code in your stylesheet to reset the default behaviour of the elements. This will remove their default characteristics and then you can customize your elements.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per what I understood, use `float:left` to align image to the left and change your HTML structure.  I think you are looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/H4F8H/12/